# cellForRowAt index path function not called

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When I try to run my code, the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function does not run for some reason.

The `numberOfSections` function works perfectly. I was thinking it was the `dataSource/delegate` function or a problem with the cell.

Would really appreciate finding solution to this problem.

```
import UIKit

class MoviesTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self


        MovieController.getAllMovies(name: "blue") { (sucess) in
            if sucess {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return MovieController.movies.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 148
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "movieCell", for: indexPath) as! MoviesTableViewCell

        let movie = MovieController.movies[indexPath.row]

        cell.movieRating.text = String(movie.vote_average)
        cell.movieRating.text = movie.overview
        cell.movieTitle.text = movie.title

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Show your code from `MoviesController`

Comment: If the `numberOfRowsInSection` is zero then the `cellForRowAt` method wouldn't be called. Make sure the `numberOfRowsInSection` is not zero.

Comment: Is `sucess` true? By the way the second `reloadData()` – which is called first in the timeline – is pointless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Print Debugging*

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    print("Number of section called")
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("Number of rows in section called")
    print("Movies count: ", MovieController.movies.count)
    return MovieController.movies.count
}
```

If `Number of section called` not printed to console: you have issue with `tableView` and It's `DataSource`

else if `Movies Count: 0`: `tableView` datasource working well and It's your `MoviewController.movies` issue. Check your `MovieController`

For the next step I need to see `MoviewController` content.

Answer (score 0):

First you don't need to make `tablevew.delegate = self` in UItableViewController its already known , but this not the issue

You should make sure that your datasource `MovieController.movies`
have data before you call , just print movies before you call

```
self.tableview.reloadData()
```

Comment: Thank you. That was the problem, my laptop crashed after I asked that question. I apologise

Answer (score 0):

There are number of cases which prevent your `cellForRowAt` to be called.

1. If your array `MovieController.movies` has 0 objects/elements, which you have return as `MovieController.movies.count` in your `numberOfRowsInSection`.
2. If you have placed your UITableView in storyboard or xib and because of any reason your UITableView don't get enough height to show your content in that case also your `cellForRowAt` will never be called. In most of the cases the height is 0.

Comment: Thank you! The problem was that my data had nothing in it yet. Im sorry I replied late, my computer crashed yesterday